# Disable streetview, full screen of google map in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, react-redux

I used this npm package, **"google-maps-react"** [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-maps-react), is there any way to disable/remove full screen, streetview feature? I tried to find ways but seems no way for this library, pls help me.
Here is my code.

```
const myComp = props => {
  return(
    <Map
                  google={props.google}
                  style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
                  zoom={12}
                  onDragend={handleMapCenterChanged}
                  onReady={fetchPlaces}
                >
               
    </Map>
  )
}
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  {}
)(
  GoogleApiWrapper({
    apiKey: API_KEY,
    LoadingContainer: LoadingContainer,
  })(myComp)
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable these controls when using the google-maps-react library, you need to set the [parameters](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-maps-react#:%7E:text=The%20following%20props%20are%20boolean%20values%20for%20presence%20of%20controls%20on%20the%20map%3A) for each control to `false`. You can follow this:

```
   <Map
            google={this.props.google}
            zoom={14}
            style={mapStyles}
            initialCenter={{ lat: 40.756795, lng: -73.954298 }}
            fullscreenControl={false}
            streetViewControl={false}
          />
```